# 3D object created using Three.JS/WebGL not loading in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, firefox-addon, three.js

I have created a 3d Object using Three.js examples, they are working fine in Chrome and IE 11, but its not loading on Firefox, I have latest version of Firefox (FF 27.0)

In the Fiddle I have created, nothing is loading on Firefox, where as in my application, I am getting this **error in Firefox**:

[image]

Here is my Code:
**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS**

```
    // revolutions per second
var angularSpeed = 0.2;
var lastTime = 0;

// this function is executed on each animation frame
function animate() {
    // update
    var time = (new Date()).getTime();
    var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
    var angleChange = angularSpeed * timeDiff * 2 * Math.PI / 1000;
    cylinder.rotation.x += angleChange;
    cylinder.rotation.z += angleChange;
    lastTime = time;

    // render
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // request new frame
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        animate();
    });
}

// renderer
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(container.offsetWidth, container.offsetHeight);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 700;

// scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// cylinder
// API: THREE.CylinderGeometry(bottomRadius, topRadius, height, segmentsRadius, segmentsHeight)
var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(150, 150, 400, 100, 100, false), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    // light
    specular: '#cccccc',
    // intermediate
    color: '#666666',
    // dark
    emissive: '#444444',
    shininess: 100
}));
cylinder.overdraw = true;
cylinder.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.2;
//cylinder.rotation.y = Math.PI * 0.5;
scene.add(cylinder);

// add subtle ambient lighting
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
scene.add(ambientLight);

// directional lighting
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
scene.add(directionalLight);

// start animation
animate();
```

**FIDDLE for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/Mvz2b/1/**

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Comment: As a first step, link to the current version of three.js in your fiddle: `threejs.org/build/three.min.js`.

Comment: Tried that... still not working!!!

Comment: I did not say that would solve the problem; it was just a tip to avoid using an old version of the library.

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox 29

Comment: The fiddle works for me in Firefox 27.0.1 Win7 Intel integrated

Comment: It works as is, Firefox 27, Windows 7, ATI Radeon HD 4670, Catalyst 13.9

Comment: working for me too. just check that any plugins in Firefox are not messing up with the JS that is being loaded.I have also seen some viruses being able to do that so you, can give that too a shot.

Comment: Thanks guys for confirming!!! Any idea what pluggin I might be missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution Guys!!!

Seems I have an older graphic card and WebGL is enabled in Firefox if you have NVIDIA or ATI graphic card manufactured after 2007.

To enable Manually, All I did:

> Type about:config in address bar and in the search box type webgl. To
>   enable WebGL, set webgl.force-enabled to true.

And after making these changes I tested my **Fiddle "http://jsfiddle.net/Mvz2b/1/**" in **`Firefox (version 27.0)`** and its working fine, whereas initially I was getting a some JS error for WebGL in mentioned in my script.

Here is the Article which provided the solution **:**

**[How to Enable WebGL in Firefox [For Blacklisted Graphic Cards]](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/03/how-to-enable-webgl-in-firefox-for.html)**

Hope this will help someone in future!!

Comment: Thanks for sharing answer so it can help others when we come across this via search